# How to get the Instagram video URL in Android WebView?

Tags: android, url, webview, instagram

HI android guys I m developing an android app in which i m loading instagram(www.instagram.com) on webview,
what i want: i want to get the playing video url in webview.
Problem: the problem is that while i click on instagram video it does not open on seperate page,that's why i can't get video url!
in the given image the video playing on the same page,..
there is any solution how can I get video URL?[image]

Comment: are you used WebViewClient

Comment: yes bro, i m using

Comment: yes bro i m using webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code to get url from the `Webview`

```
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                  //here you will get url 
                  Log.d("getcurrenturl",""+url);

              }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
}
```

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper post your code what you are tried.

Comment: bro its working for other urls not for instagram.com

Comment: webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/), is a library i used several times and works perfectly. You only have to parse the HTML response passing the URL you pass to the webview, then search for the tag of the videos and in the "href" atribute you will find the URL of the video.

pd: i didnt test this, so maybe you will have to work little more, but i used that library and i could download all the images in the page, so i supose it will be the same with videos.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the Instagram Video URL is to add `?__a=1` at the end of the post you're trying to target (i.e. `https://www.instagram.com/p/BqTd8dhFKLN/?__a=1`).

You can then navigate to `["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["video_url"]` or `["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["edge_sidecar_to_children"]["edges"][carousel_number]["node"]["video_url"]` (depending on whether the post is a carrousel) which will give you the video URL.